# Guzzle error 100 sending request to Facebook Messenger Bot Platform

Tags: php, guzzle, facebook-messenger

I am developing a Facebook Messenger bot using php.
I want to set the Greeting text as explained in the official documentation: [Greeting text](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/greeting-text)

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type":"greeting",
  "greeting":{
    "text":"New message."
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=my_token"
```

The command above works and I get:

```
{"result":"Successfully updated greeting"}
```

I wrote the corresponding php code exploiting Guzzle:

```
$data = '{"setting_type":"greeting","greeting":{"text":"New message."}}';
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->post(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=' . $my_token,
       [
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
            'body' => $data,
            'debug' => true
       ]
);
```

But it don't work..  please notice that the php code above works fine with others methods of the Send API reference such as [Text message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/text-message) .

What I am doing wrong? 
I will provide any other information upon request. Thanks.

Here's the complete debug output:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 31.13.86.8...
*   Trying 2a03:2880:f008:1:face:b00c:0:1...
* Immediate connect fail for 2a03:2880:f008:1:face:b00c:0:1: Network is unreachable
* Connected to graph.facebook.com (31.13.86.8) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=CA; L=Menlo Park; O=Facebook, Inc.; CN=*.facebook.com
*    start date: 2014-08-28 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-12-30 12:00:00 GMT
*    subjectAltName: graph.facebook.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /v2.6/me/messages?access_token=my_token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.35.0 PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17
Host: graph.facebook.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 62

* upload completely sent off: 62 out of 62 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#100) The parameter recipient is required"
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-store
< facebook-api-version: v2.7
< Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
< Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
< x-fb-trace-id: HNn9aIOgqyq
< x-fb-rev: 2613595
< X-FB-Debug: oD3GTGNh0GIu2muJmZoan9896nrrxC+P+L+G3iYoRZ3cnYh7k+cOl7JRtOvuCedR3gYkUqs2rkTmQ8Nj3plZrg==
< Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 21:07:00 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 128
< 
* Connection #0 to host graph.facebook.com left intact
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=my_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter recipient is required","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"HNn9aI (truncated...)
' in /var/www/html/messenger-bot/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:107
```

Comment: In the Guzzle, you're sending it to: `v2.6/me/messages`, but in the CURL you're sending it to `v2.6/me/thread_settings`

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error, with thread_settings works fine!